# how to turn latex figure by 90 degrees along with the caption?

Tags: floats, rotating

The following code rotates the figure as I want to, so now my Y axis is parallel to the shorter edge of my A4 sheet. However, my caption is still parallel to the shorter edge of my sheet.

How can I make the caption follow the figure and be parallel to the large edge of my sheet?

```
\begin{figure}[p]

\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.3\textwidth, angle =90 ]{Graphs/1.png}
\caption{Box plot of number of positions sent per iteration using this scheme}
\label{fig:awesome_image}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: rotating package and `sidewaysfigure`

Answer (score 80):

The `rotating` package introduces a `sidewaysfigure` environment that lends itself well to that:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle(2,1.5);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Box plot of number of positions sent per iteration using this scheme}
    \label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need to specify the `[p]` ("page by itself") location directive when starting the `sidewaysfigure` environment: The figure will be placed automatically on a page by itself.

Comment: @Mico Ok. Fixed.

Comment: It really upsets me that the `sidewaysfigure` is read from bottom to top, is there a way to make it read top to bottom?

Comment: @Stormie, you can load the `rotating` package with the `figuresleft` option: `\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}`

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Thank you very much