# Rotating: Sideways figure with Section title

Tags: floats, rotating

Is there any way I can fit a sideways figure using the `rotating` package onto the same page as the title of the section?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\subsection{My sideways figure}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle(2,1.5);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Box plot of number of positions sent per iteration using this scheme}
\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

P.S. Credit to @Jubobs for his example of how to use the `rotating`package ([how to turn latex figure by 90 degrees along with the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101645/how-to-turn-latex-figure-by-90-degrees-alongwith-the-caption)).

Comment: What about either using a normal `figure` environment and just rotate the picture by enclosing the `tikzpicture` environment in `\rotatebox{90}{...picture...}`,  or if you want to rotate the caption as well, using the solution [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44427/rotate-picture-with-caption)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elemental approach with two `turn` environments and `minipage`s. The result is the same with or without the added  *Lore ipsum* dummy text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\subsection{My sideways figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b][8cm][b]{6cm}
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \fill[blue] (0,0) rectangle(2,1.5);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{turn}
\end{minipage}
\begin{turn}{90}
\begin{minipage}[c][1cm][c]{8cm}
\caption{Box plot of number of positions sent per iteration using this scheme.}
\label{fig:awesome_image}
\end{minipage} 
\end{turn}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: that feels like a dirt hack, but i worked and i was able to combine a rotated picture+caption with a section in one page, so ...yeaah.