# Place a subsubsection and a sidewaysfigure on a page

Tags: rotating, sections-paragraphs

Since I have some graphics which have to be printed very large so you can see the details, I want to put them in the appendix of my document. Now to easily navigate the appendix I want to place a `subsubsection` and a `sidewaysfigure` on each page.

```
\subsubsection{Paper 01 - Kalman}
\label{apx:plots-paper01-kalman}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
        height=0.7\textheight,
        keepaspectratio
    ]{verificationMeasurementPaper01v2/KalmanDistance2.eps}

    \caption{...}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\subsubsection{Paper 01 - Kalman (100 Samples)}
\label{apx:plots-paper01-kalman-100}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
        height=0.7\textheight,
        keepaspectratio
    ]{verificationMeasurementPaper01v2/KalmanDistance2-100-samples.eps}

    \caption{...}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

But now the `subsection` and the `subsubsection` are printed on the first page and after that there is always one page with one image.

How can I change this, so every `subsubsection` stays with the corresponding image on one page?

Both of the duplicated answers do not work. The `subsubsections` are still on the same place and not in front of the corresponding image.

Comment: another possible duplicate: [landscape figure on different page to heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168309/579)

Comment: Can you make your example compilable, please?

Comment: Maybe your image together with the caption is to large to fit on the page together with the heading. But this is speculative, because we still do not have a compilable example.