# sidewaysfigure with non-rotated section-title

Tags: floats, rotating

I have a `sidewaysfigure` with consisting of 6 subfigures. As this is the first figure that appear in my appendix, I need to have a non-rotatet section-title. Following this question [Rotating: Sideways figure with Section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144845/rotating-sideways-figure-with-section-title) I tried to put my figure in a `minipage`. But the result is that I have half of the figure on top (cut-off) and then in the middle of the page the section title.

I give u an example:

```
%General Layout
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}

%Font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%Graphs and Diagrams
%\usepackage{subgraphic}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating} %remove 'demo' option for real file
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


%Tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape, longtable}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
   justification=centering,
   singlelinecheck=off, font=bf]{caption}

%%%%\usepackage[labelfont=md]{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries 
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%% Journal Conventions %%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}} 
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\textsc{ABSTRACT}}
\makeatletter
% we need a period (.) after sectioning numbers, but not in cites thereto.
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{0.5em}}

\long\def\@makefigcaption#1#2{%
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip
 %#1\\\footnotesize#2
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\footnotesize\bf#1.\footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\footnotesize{\textbf{#1.}} footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\textbf{#1.} footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa
 \footnotesize\textbf{#1.} \footnotesize#2
 \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
 \textbf{#1.} #2\par
 \else
  \global \@minipagefalse
  \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
 \fi
 \vskip\belowcaptionskip} 

\renewcommand{\figure}{\let\@makecaption\@makefigcaption\@float{figure}}

\long\def\@maketblcaption#1#2{%
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip %Same size for Numbering and Caption of Tables
 \begin{center}\normalsize\bf#1\\\normalsize#2\end{center}
% \sbox\@tempboxa{\textbf{#1.} #2}%
% \global \@minipagefalse
% \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
 \vskip\belowcaptionskip} 

\renewcommand{\table}{\let\@makecaption\@maketblcaption\@float{table}}
%\renewcommand{\sidewaystable}{\let\@makecaption\@maketblcaption\@float{sidewaystable}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Appendix}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=md}
\centering
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b][15cm][b]{15cm}
\begin{turn}{90}
%\caption{Cumulated Average Index-Adjusted CDS Return for Extreme Earnings Decile Portfolios \label{fig:CASC}}
%\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
%\footnotesize test test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test 
%\bigskip
%\end{minipage}
\subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE1}} \quad \bigskip
\subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE2}}\quad 
\subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE3}} \quad \\
\subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE1}} \quad 
\subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE2}}\quad 
\subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE3}} \quad 
%\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
%\bigskip
%Figure continues on next page
%\bigskip
%\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Furthermore, when I use `sidewaysfigure` the figures are equally "distributed" in a 2x3 (sideways view). Using the `minipage` environment just cuts them off. 
Additionally, I would like to have the subcaptions in non-bold while the caption in bold. I tried to it with loading the `subcaption` package with `labelfont=md` options as well as directly "in front" of the figure with `\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=md}` (and [sidewaysfigure]}. But the subcaption of my subfigure are still bold.

thank you very much

edit:

this is the code I am trying to compile:

```
%General Layout
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}

%Font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%Graphs and Diagrams
%\usepackage{subgraphic}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating} %remove 'demo' option for real file
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


%Tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape, longtable}
\usepackage{hvfloat}

\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
   justification=centering,
   singlelinecheck=off, font=bf]{caption}

%%%%\usepackage[labelfont=md]{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries 
\sisetup{detect-weight=true,detect-inline-weight=math}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{array}


\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%% Journal Conventions %%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}} 
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\textsc{ABSTRACT}}
\makeatletter
% we need a period (.) after sectioning numbers, but not in cites thereto.
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{0.5em}}

\long\def\@makefigcaption#1#2{%
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip
 %#1\\\footnotesize#2
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\footnotesize\bf#1.\footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\footnotesize{\textbf{#1.}} footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\textbf{#1.} footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa
 \footnotesize\textbf{#1.} \footnotesize#2
 \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
 \textbf{#1.} #2\par
 \else
  \global \@minipagefalse
  \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
 \fi
 \vskip\belowcaptionskip} 

\renewcommand{\figure}{\let\@makecaption\@makefigcaption\@float{figure}}

\long\def\@maketblcaption#1#2{%
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip %Same size for Numbering and Caption of Tables
 \begin{center}\normalsize\bf#1\\\normalsize#2\end{center}
% \sbox\@tempboxa{\textbf{#1.} #2}%
% \global \@minipagefalse
% \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
 \vskip\belowcaptionskip} 

\renewcommand{\table}{\let\@makecaption\@maketblcaption\@float{table}}
%\renewcommand{\sidewaystable}{\let\@makecaption\@maketblcaption\@float{sidewaystable}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Appendix}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelfont=md}
\centering
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b][15cm][b]{15cm}
\begin{turn}{90}
%\caption{Cumulated Average Index-Adjusted CDS Return for Extreme Earnings Decile Portfolios \label{fig:CASC}}
%\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
%\footnotesize test test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test testtest test test test 
%\bigskip
%\end{minipage}
\subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE1}} \quad \bigskip
\subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE2}}\quad 
\subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE3}} \quad \\
\subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE1}} \quad 
\subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE2}}\quad 
\subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE3}} \quad 
%\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
%\bigskip
%Figure continues on next page
%\bigskip
%\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: here is a reduced version (I just commented out all packages from which I know it would worked without).

```
%General Layout
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}

%Font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Language

%Graphs and Diagrams
%\usepackage{subgraphic}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating} %remove 'demo' option for real file
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

%\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
%   justification=centering,
%   singlelinecheck=off, font=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Appendix}
\centering
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b][15cm][b]{15cm}
\begin{turn}{90}
\subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE1}} \quad \bigskip
\subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE2}}\quad 
\subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE3}} \quad \\
\subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE1}} \quad 
\subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE2}}\quad 
\subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.31\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE3}} \quad 
\end{turn}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and that is the output:
[image]

ant that is what I would like to achieve (Note I painted the section-title manually):
[image]

EDIT:
Here is the example that is almost what I wanted. Now the question arises on how to modify the caption just(!) for figures: I need them to be bold and left aligned while captions for my tables are supposed to be centered (therefore, I global definition might not be possible).

```
%General Layout
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}

%Font encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
   justification=centering, labelsep=period,
   singlelinecheck=off, font=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%% Journal of Finance %%%%%%%%%%

%These conventions are taken from Jiri Woschitz and Guido Rosenast

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\Roman{table}} 
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\textsc{ABSTRACT}}
\makeatletter
% we need a period (.) after sectioning numbers, but not in cites thereto.
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{0.5em}}

\long\def\@makefigcaption#1#2{%
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip
 %#1\\\footnotesize#2
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\footnotesize\bf#1.\footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\footnotesize{\textbf{#1.}} footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa{\textbf{#1.} footnotesize#2}%
 %\sbox\@tempboxa
 \footnotesize\textbf{#1.} \footnotesize#2
 \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
 \textbf{#1.} #2\par
 \else
  \global \@minipagefalse
  \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
 \fi
 \vskip\belowcaptionskip} 

\renewcommand{\figure}{\let\@makecaption\@makefigcaption\@float{figure}}

\long\def\@maketblcaption#1#2{%
 \vskip\abovecaptionskip %Same size for Numbering and Caption of Tables
 \begin{center}\normalsize\bf#1\\\normalsize#2\end{center}
% \sbox\@tempboxa{\textbf{#1.} #2}%
% \global \@minipagefalse
% \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
 \vskip\belowcaptionskip} 

\renewcommand{\table}{\let\@makecaption\@maketblcaption\@float{table}}
%\renewcommand{\sidewaystable}{\let\@makecaption\@maketblcaption\@float{sidewaystable}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0.1cm}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-2mm}

%%%%%%%%%% End: Journal of Finance%%%%%%%%%%

\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=md}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\newpage

\section{Appendix}


  \centering
  \begin{figure}[htp]
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \section{Appendix} \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
  \end{minipage}
    \begin{turn}{90}    
      \begin{minipage}{0.85\textheight} 
      \caption{Cumulated Average Index-Adjusted CDS Return for Extreme Earnings Decile Portfolios \label{fig:CASC}} \vspace{-3mm}
testestestt estestestteste stesttestestesttestestesttestestesttestestes
testestesttestest esttestestestteste stesttes testestvtestestest
testestesttestestestt estestesttestestestteste stesttestestesttesteste
testestestte stestesttestestesttestestesttestestesttestestest \bigskip \bigskip \\
\subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.27\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE1}} \quad \bigskip
\subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.27\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE2}} \quad
\subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.27\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE3}} \quad 
\subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.27\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE1}} \quad
\subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.27\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE2}} \quad 
\subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.27\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE3}} \quad 
\end{minipage}
\end{turn}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're loading the `subcaption` package, yet you use syntax of the `subfig` package to create the subfloats. Please post a compilable example, so that others can focus on the problem you're describing rather than on figuring out how to debug your code.

Comment: Dear Mico, thank you for your answer. I do not really understand what you mean by using the `syntax` package to create the subfloats. The code I am using is from a question and solution posted (by another user). Does the code above as such not working for you? because I can run it "without problems".

Comment: I did *not* say you should use the `syntax` package. Your example code will not compile as posted. This is, in part, because the code uses `\subfloat` instructions yet loads the `subcaption` package -- which does not provide a macro with named `\subfloat`. The `subfig` package does provide a macro named `subfloat`, but the instruction `\usepackage{subfig}` is currently commented out. I don't think it's fair to expect the people who you are asking for help to have to spend significant amounts of time tracking down basic syntactical errors.

Comment: Dear Mico, I am sorry, `Syntx`was a mistake. I use TeXmaker to run the code and as long as I have `caption`and `subcaption`the code runs. When I include `subfig` an error appears (even when when comment out the first two packages). Do you have any suggestion how to replace `\subfloat`. I have this code from another question and as it worked fine (by now) i did not question it.

Comment: What I've pointed out is that the code, *as you have posted it*, does not "run". I stand by this claim.

Comment: Can you try it again? because for me it works (I just copy pasted the entire code - the only problem might be due to the *.eps-file which only I have), it just does not look very nice (because of the issue mentioned in the question). Therefore, I have no idea how to modify the code to make it run.

Comment: Any edits you may have made recently to the code don't seem to show up. I've made the following edits: (i) commented out the instruction `\usepackage[labelfont=md]{subcaption}`; (ii) uncommented the instruction `\usepackage{subfig}`; and (iii) replaced `\usepackage{rotating}` with `\usepackage[demo]{rotating}`, i.e., I added the option `demo`. The code will now compile, though I don't know if the code is actually what you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for the edits, but now the code does not compile anymore with the error: "Option clash for package caption". I have been checking, but `\caption` is there only once.

Comment: I must say I don't know what's going on. The modified code runs without an error message on my system (MacTeX2014, with all package updates applied). Do you maybe have an older (obsolete?) TeX distribution?

Comment: I am using the editor Texmaker 4.2 (compiled with Qt 5.2.1 and Poppler 0.22.5) Copyright (c) 2003-2014 by Pascal Brachet. I downloaded it mid-July 2014. 

There is a newer version since August Texmaker 4.3. Do you think that migh the problem? or is it because of my "MiKTex 2.9"?

Comment: I guess the only option left is that you and I aren't compiling the same code.

Comment: I copy & paste the code I am trying to compile from my Texmaker. For me it seems the same. :/

Comment: If @Mico's code is the first block of code above, it compiles fine for me (though the output is a mess). The same for the second block of code. Is this supposed to be different? If so, what is different? It would help a *great* deal if you would please reduce your code to a **minimal** working example. There is surely a bunch of stuff here you do not need to reproduce the problem, and reducing it appropriately will make it a lot easier to be sure whether you are or are not compiling the same code. You can remove all the commented lines which are not directly relevant for a start.

Comment: Note that TeXmaker is merely an editor and has nothing to do with the compilation itself.

Comment: @cfr - I concur that the two code blocks appear to be essentially identical.

Comment: When I delete the options for the `caption` package I can compile the code. In the log-file I found that `caption`and `caption3` is loaded.

Comment: That is is better but still not very minimal. Moreover, please delete irrelevant lines rather than commenting them as the latter makes it much harder to see what is going on. You cannot need `tikz` or `pdfpages` or `babel`, either.

Comment: What is it meant to look like? As it stands, the figure is going to be too large to fit on the same page as the section heading because three lots of almost one-third of the text height plus spacing plus room for the section title is going to be greater than the text height, almost certainly.

Comment: I would not mind to reduce the size of the picture in order to make it fit. I used `sidewaysfigure`, but as it is pointed out in another question the `sidewaysfigure` "occupies" the whole page. Therefore, I was looking for an alternative to get section title + kind of sidewaysfigure (incl. caption, subcaptions and textdescription) as shown in the last graphic. With `minipage`I hoped I could divide the page into a small part for the section-title and the major part for the graphics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the kind of thing I think you want although I'm not sure. You can fiddle with the sizes to make the most of the space but you need things smaller than in the MWE unless you want more than 2 lines of sub-figures which is another option.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Graphs and Diagrams
%\usepackage{subgraphic}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating} %remove 'demo' option for real file
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
justification=centering,
singlelinecheck=off, font=bf]{caption}

\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}

\long\def\@makefigcaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \footnotesize\textbf{#1.} \footnotesize#2
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
  \textbf{#1.} #2\par
  \else
  \global \@minipagefalse
  \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\renewcommand{\figure}{\let\@makecaption\@makefigcaption\@float{figure}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \section{Appendix}

  \centering
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{turn}{90}
      \begin{minipage}{.75\textheight}
        \subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE1}} \quad
        \subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE2}}\quad
        \subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE3}} \quad

        \subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE1}} \quad
        \subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE2}}\quad
        \subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE3}} \quad
      \end{minipage}
    \end{turn}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: 3x2 figures rotated 90 degrees with section title]

## Update

To move the figure downwards, you can insert some vertical space before and after, followed by a `\clearpage`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Graphs and Diagrams
%\usepackage{subgraphic}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating} %remove 'demo' option for real file
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
justification=centering,
singlelinecheck=off, font=bf]{caption}

\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}

\long\def\@makefigcaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \footnotesize\textbf{#1.} \footnotesize#2
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
  \textbf{#1.} #2\par
  \else
  \global \@minipagefalse
  \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\renewcommand{\figure}{\let\@makecaption\@makefigcaption\@float{figure}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \section{Appendix}

  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{turn}{90}
      \begin{minipage}{.75\textheight}
        \subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE1}} \quad
        \subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE2}}\quad
        \subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE3}} \quad

        \subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE1}} \quad
        \subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE2}}\quad
        \subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE3}} \quad
      \end{minipage}
    \end{turn}
  \end{figure}
  \vfill
  \clearpage
  New page

\end{document}
```

[image: moving down...]

## Update II

As requested, here is a way to customise the captions for figures and tables:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm, top=3cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%Graphs and Diagrams
%\usepackage{subgraphic}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{rotating} %remove 'demo' option for real file
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[labelsep=newline,% line break after label
justification=centering,
singlelinecheck=off, font=bf]{caption}


\makeatletter% Set distance from top of page to first float
\setlength{\@fptop}{5pt}

\long\def\@makefigcaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \footnotesize\textbf{#1.} \footnotesize#2
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
  \textbf{#1.} #2\par
  \else
  \global \@minipagefalse
  \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}

\renewcommand{\figure}{\let\@makecaption\@makefigcaption\@float{figure}}

\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{my-figures}{%
  \def\tempa{figure}%
  \def\tempb{#1}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb(\textbf{#2})\else{\centering(\textbf{#2})}}
\captionsetup{labelformat=my-figures,labelsep=quad}

\begin{document}

  \section{Appendix}

  \vfill
  {\centering
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{turn}{90}
      \begin{minipage}{.75\textheight}
        \subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE1}} \quad
        \subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE2}}\quad
        \subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Full Sample]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_full_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:fullDSUE3}} \quad

        \subfloat[DSUE1 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue1.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE1}} \quad
        \subfloat[DSUE2 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue2.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE2}}\quad
        \subfloat[DSUE3 $-$ Pre-Crisis]{\includegraphics[width=0.225\textheight]{aasc_precrisis_dsue3.eps}\label{fig:preDSUE3}} \quad
        \caption{Figure Caption}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{turn}
  \end{figure}}
  \vfill
  \clearpage
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        A & table\\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table Caption}
  \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: figures and tables...]

Comment: dear cfr, Thank you very much for the code. Actually, that is what I am looking for. Would it possible to move the figures "closer" to the bottom in other words, to center the figures between the space below appendix and the bottom of the page?

Comment: @eternity1 See my update.

Comment: dear cfr, I could make it work but I still have one issue about the caption: Is it possible to modify the captions just for figures? In my code captions for tables are supposed to be centered and bold and captions for figures should be left aligned and bold.

Comment: @eternity1 See my update but note that you just need to look at the documentation for `caption` really. Note that the format of the figure caption is being determined by your customisation in the preamble, I think, so tweak or remove that if you don't want it that way. Or remove the parentheses or whatever from my definition. (It looks odd to have parentheses and a full-stop but having them here for demonstration purposes seemed useful.)

Comment: Dear cfr, Thank you for the update. Inspired by your minigpage example I have found a way to "keep" section-title and figure together: I put the section-title in a (horizontal) minipage before the (vertical) minipage which contents my figure. In this way I can control the distance and the "textsize" of any caption or whatsoever. Thank you very much for your help!