# Sidewaysfigure in a page with section title

Tags: sectioning, rotating, sidewaysfigure

I have a `sidewaysfigure` just after a `section` title. The figure is not too big for requires a new page. How can I indicate to put the `sidewaysfigure` after the section title?

**Note:** I have a serie of this figures

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Title Section}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure caption 1}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure caption 2}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196616/sidewaysfigure-with-non-rotated-section-title?rq=1 if it can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at `rotating.sty`, I believe this happens because `sidewaysfigure` puts the contents in a floating box whose size is `\textheight`. With the section heading on the page, there is insufficient space remaining on the page to place a `\textheight` sideways figure. This causes the `sidewaysfigure` to float to the next page.

The solution, I suggest, is don't use a float, which means don't use `sidewaysfigure`. An `adjustbox` can be used here. I put the two figures centered horizontally using the center key of `adjustbox` and vertically using `\vspace*{\fill}` at the top and bottom of the page content.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{Title Section}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90,center,caption=Caption 1,nofloat=figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90,center,caption=Caption 2,nofloat=figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{adjustbox}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It was I who was confused. I've already deleted my earlier comment. Sorry.

Comment: But captions must turn like figures too.